# Exotic spectrum of Laplace operator

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, laplacian

Given a closed Riemannian manifold and a generalized Laplace $\Delta$ operator, 
it is well known that $\Delta$ has discrete spectrum $(\lambda_n)_n$ (arranged in a increasing way, not counting multiplicities). 
By a (consequence of a) result of Colin de Verdière, given any finite strictly increasing sequence $a_1,\cdots,a_k$ of 
strictly positive numbers,
there exists a Riemannian manifold and a Laplace operator on it such that the first k+1 eigenvalues are 
exactly, $0,a_1,\cdots,a_k$.

My question is about what's happening at infinity. More precisely, since usually 
the spectrum of a Laplace operator is a quadratic polynomial (in the sense that 
 {$\lambda_n : {n\geq 0}$} is of the form {$P(n) : n\geq 0$} where $P$ is a quadratic polynomial),
is there a Laplace operator (on a closed manifold) such that there is no $n_0$ such that {$\lambda_n : {n\geq n_0}$} is of the form {$P(n) : n\geq 0$} where $P$ is a quadratic polynomial ?

My question could be reformulated : do you know example where the explicit (exact) eigenvalues (not asymptotics of them) are (after a certain rank) not given by a formula of the form 
$a n^2 + bn +c$ where $a,b,c$ are constants (for example some kind of 
fraction P(n)/Q(n) where the degree of P is 3 and the degree of Q is one...)

[Edit : precisions]

Comment: What do you mean by "Spectrum of a Laplace operator is a quadratic polynomial"?

Answer (score 10):

Regarding the asymptotic behavior of the spectrum of the Laplacian (or, as the OP puts it, the behavior at infinity), the most basic result is **Weyl's asymptotic formula** (see [Chavel's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0121706400), p.172): let $(M,g)$ be a compact manifold with $\dim M=n$ and $0=\lambda_0<\lambda_1\leq \lambda_2\leq\dots$ be the eigenvalues of the Laplacian, each distinct eigenvalue repeated according to its multiplicity. Denote by $N(\lambda)=\sum_{\lambda_j\leq\lambda} 1$ the number of eigenvalues (counted with multiplicity) that are $\leq\lambda$. Then

$$N(\lambda)\sim vol(M,g)\frac{vol(B^n)}{(2\pi)^n}\lambda^{n/2}, \quad \mbox{as} \quad\lambda\to+\infty,$$

where $vol(B^n)=\frac{\pi^{n/2}}{\Gamma(n/2+1)}$ is the volume of the unit ball of $\mathbb R^n$. In particular,

$$(\lambda_k)^{n/2}\sim\frac{(2\pi)^n}{vol(B^n)}\frac{k}{vol(M,g)}, \quad \mbox{as}\quad k\to+\infty.$$

> Thus, the asymptotic behavior of the eigenvalues **cannot be prescribed** - it has to satisfy the above.

---

Also, as far as I understand, Colin de Verdière's result is stronger than stated. Namely, given **any** compact connected manifold M, with $\dim M\geq 3$, and any finite sequence $0\leq a_1\leq\dots\leq a_k$, there exists a Riemannian metric on $M$ such that the first eigenvalues in the spectrum of its Laplacian are $0\leq a_1\leq\dots\leq a_k$.

Answer (score 5):

For a generic metric on an $m$-dimensional the manifold the eigenvalues of the Laplacian are all simple.  Fix such a metric and denote the coresponding eigenvalues by

$$ \lambda_1, \lambda_2,\cdots $$

Using Weyl's asymptotic expansion we conclude that

$$\lambda_n\sim \text{const}\cdot n^{m/2}. $$

Thus for any polynomial $P$ of degree $d>m/2$ we have

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \lambda_n/P(n) = 0. $$